# C# FluentAPI Many to Many with EF

Tags: database, many-to-many

Having some issues regarding the many to many relationship when trying to connect to a database. The problems comes when i add data to the many to many table in the database. (Database is Windows SQL)

DataModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace PublisherDataModel
{
    public class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {
            this.Authors = new HashSet<Author>();
        }
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public Author()
        {
            this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
        }

        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

    public class PublisherEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

        public PublisherEntities()
            : base(@"DatabaseConnection")
        {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                   .HasMany<Author>(b => b.Authors)
                   .WithMany(a => a.Books)
                   .Map(ab =>
                   {
                       ab.MapLeftKey("BookRefId");
                       ab.MapRightKey("AuthorRefId");
                       ab.ToTable("BookAuthor");
                   });
        }
    }
}
```

And Controller for both Authors and Books (only posted one)

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using PublisherDataModel;

namespace PublisherDataService.Controllers
{
    public class AuthorsController : ApiController
    {
        private PublisherEntities db = new PublisherEntities();

        // GET api/Authors
        public IQueryable<Author> GetAuthors()
        {
            return db.Authors.Include(a => a.Books);
        }

        // GET api/Authors/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAuthor(int id)
        {
            Author author = db.Authors.Find(id);
            if (author == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(author);
        }

        // PUT api/Authors/5
        public IHttpActionResult PutAuthor(int id, Author author)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != author.AuthorId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(author).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AuthorExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST api/Authors
        [ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostAuthor(Author author)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Authors.Add(author);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = author.AuthorId }, author);
        }

        // DELETE api/Authors/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteAuthor(int id)
        {
            Author author = db.Authors.Find(id);
            if (author == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Authors.Remove(author);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(author);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool AuthorExists(int id)
        {
            return db.Authors.Count(e => e.AuthorId == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The result when no data added to many to many table:
[Result before adding data to the table](https://i.imgur.com/aVqAwcW)

The result when data is added to the many to many table:
[Result after adding data to the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66zNW.jpg)

Also get error no matter if data is added to the many to many table where it should say what info you should expect and what format it should be in.
[Format error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IZDW.jpg)

So what am i doing wrong here, is there a problem with the many to many relationship in the DataModel? From what i understood the ICollection was supposed to be a navigation property.

Also how do you get the many to many information from browser? I saw some examples using /api/Authors/4/Books but that does not work when u get error when trying to add many to many data in the database.

Thanks. Happy to add more information if needed.